# How to search for specific text that is changed inside a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am stuck on one problem that I hardly can describe that easily.
I fetch JSON data from an RESTful API that contains several objects which are then placed as text inside a **Textarea** field, so it can be edited. After the edit is done, a button is clicked and then that string is saved somewhere else in the DB.
So far so good.

Problem comes in the scenario when an user edits that text in the Textarea field and then triggers the API again (answers another questions from the form on the same website), so that fetches another data into that Textarea, but the edited data should be present as well.

E.g. First time there are 2 sentences inserted inside the Textarea:

> The car is painted red. The car has 4 wheels.

So then the user changes the first answer in the form, so the Textarea looks like this:

> The car is painted blue. The car has 4 wheels.

I got that figured out with the Javascript replace() function, just find the sentence "The car is painted red." and replace it with the "The car is painted blue."

```
   document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = journalTextareaString.replace(tempPreviousAnswer,tempChangedAnswer);
```

If the text is edited like before/after the sentence, the sentence is replaced normally with the new one, all the added text from the user stays. For example the user has manually inputed some extra text:

> I love my car. The car is painted red. The car is nice. The car has 4
>   wheels.

Now if he switches the car to color blue on the form, the manually edited text stays and only the sentence with the color is changed:

> I love my car. The car is painted blue. The car is nice. The car has 4
>   wheels.

But how do I do it when a user has edited the text from inside the sentence, for example he puts a word "chrome" in between the sentence, like:

> The car is painted chrome red. The car has 4 wheels.

Thanks.

Comment: So are you editing the first text and THEN saving it to the database or are you saving after ALL of the text areas are edited?

Comment: After the textarea field is edited (there is only one textarea field) and the confirm button beneath is pressed the edited text is saved into the DB.

Comment: So in a sense, you are losing the state of the first object because you're changing it.  Now it is mixed in with the other one.  You may want to do one of two things.  Save the state of the 1st object and the re-retrieve it via ajax or whatever you're using OR open yet anohter text box for editing the next question.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I save the state of the first object if it's changed ? 
You're saying to add an textbox for each sentence, so that way I can keep track of the changed sentence, or ?

Comment: Yes.  Exactly.  The tough thing here is you are appending the text together.  Keep them in different boxes.  This makes it next to Impossible to differentiate the different fields.  Separate them.  This makes it possible for you to roll back and also tell the difference about what was edited.

Answer (score 1):

The tough thing here is you are appending the text together.  Keep them in different boxes.  This makes it next to Impossible to differentiate the different fields.  Separate them.  This makes it possible for you to roll back and also tell the difference about what was edited.

Comment: Alright, I guess it's the only solution. 
But, my primary goal is to have a good UX. The reason I put all the text inside the textarea is that the user can get a feeling that it's all coherent and fluid and not separated.
So I'm thinking maybe not to physically put the sentences in different boxes, but to separate them with specific <div id="sentence1"> tags and dynamic id's (since I'm using AngularJS).

Comment: That might be a good idea, however, keep in mind that people might combine sentences after they are revised in one field still making it difficult to parse.

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do is merging the text of a remote party and a local party. This is a complex thing do do, and there is not a simple solution. Please let my explain why..

**Example scenario**

Lets take for example user (B) "Bob" and  user (A) "Allan". They are going to work on a document (or in your case just a string) in collaboration. There is a version 1, that they both start working on, and in the meantime you will have A and B make changes, so you get version 2 from user A. Lets call it A2, and version B from user 2, version B2.

**The problem of conflicts**

First of all, you should make sure that both these users came from version 1. So you should keep track of versions. Then, an even more complicated problem has to be solved: merge conflicts. Take for example this image:

[image: conflict of versions]

You are going to have to decide how this conflict is resolved. Is A always going to overrule B? Wich one is overruling wich one? Or are you going to just randomly put the edits of user A and B on the same position in the text together after eachother? How are you going to handle word-spacing, deletions, additions, updates?

See how this is going to cause you alot to think about?

**Solution?**

You should offer your user a way to resolve their conflicts (keep mine, keep theirs, or interactively show the conflicts), whenever you are going to run into trouble

**Use resource-locking**

Another solution is to avoid collaboration alltogether: Lock your data (make it temporarily read-only for everyone but 1 person), so that never-ever 2 people can be editing your data at the same time.

**See also**

This problem is very well known by people that used "version control systems" such as GIT, SCM and SVN. Heres how one merge application helps programmers to solve their merge-conflicts:

[image: merge conflict resolving application screenshot]

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how this correlates with my question ? It has nothing to do with "version control systems", it's pure Javascript.

Comment: Did you really read and understand what i answered? I only gave version control systems as an example of another case that has the same problem, and they also had to find a solution for it. 

I am trying to show you how the problem you have, is not solved by just making a piece of code to check the difference. You have to fully understand your problem first. What you want needs a complex solution as you can have conflicts, and you need to decide how these are solved.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but yes, it's a complex problem and I'm getting not much response anywhere. I see that you tried to be helpful by trying to take me to the core to the problem, but the point is that I'm aware what the problem is and I'm trying to find a technical solution. I mean, ok, generally you are right, but I need an idea how to solve that problem. If it's not solvable or if it's too difficult to find a solution, sure, then the I will try something else. But for now, still I'm looking for a possible solution or at least a good idea in which direction to go. Thanks.

Comment: Oh but thats the easy part right? Compare the text from left to right, word by word. Then you will see wich words in what order match on both ends. 
After that, you check the differences. If there is only some addition on one of either versions, you can keep that addition. But if there is an addition on both sides you need to make a decision on how to solve that conflict. As I am trying to say all the time.